# How to mount usb drive to nexus 5 using mount command?

Tags: android, mount, android-permissions, nexus-5, usb-otg

I read in some online sources that lolipop 5 allows mounting usb devices using otg cable without root permissions.

Another thing i saw is that the app "ES Explorer" can mount usb devices without root.

I'm  trying to mount usb device using the built in "mount" command but im recieving "permissions denied" error.

The device shows in /etc/partitions as:

```
8    0    15633408    sda
8    1    15633392    sda1
```

I tried

```
mount -t ntfs /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

and get "permission denied"

What is the right way to mount usb device?

How does ES Explorer mount usb device without root permissions?

Comment: Did you find an answer ? I'm trying to "mount" a drive, because  I want the built in music player app to automatically detect the new folder. Any suggestion ? (without rooting) (Its a nexus 5 too, using Marshmallow AOSP)

Comment: no :(  update me if you find something ..

Comment: If I plug in a USB drive to my Moto G with lollipop, Google Play music automatically sees the music and indexes it. But If I build AOSP 6.0 for my nexus 5, the built in music player does not see it, BUT, the under settings->storage I can see the drive, "explore" it, and play music. Which means that there is a way since Google Play Music can do it (on lollipop).

Comment: It seems that Marshmallow automatically mounts the drive, and you can explore it in settings. But mediastore does not automatically index it. You have to index it yourself.